# Create Dynamic Columns with Calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dynamic-columns

I have a dataframe called prices, with historical stocks prices for the following companies:

*['APPLE', 'AMAZON', 'GOOGLE']*

So far on, with the help of a friendly user, I was able to create a dataframe for each of this periods with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date

prices = pd.read_excel('database.xlsx')

companies=prices.columns
companies=list(companies)
del companies[0]

timestep = 250
prices_list = [prices[day:day + step] for day in range(len(prices) - step)]
```

Now, I need to evaluate the change in price for every period of 251 days (Price251/Price1; Price252/Price2; Price 253/Price and so on) for each one of the companies, and create a column for each one of them.

I would also like to put the column name dynamic, so I can replicate this to a much longer database.

So, I would get a dataframe similar to this:
[open image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHVYS.png)

Here you can find the dataframe head(3): [Initial Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8jGe.png)

Comment: Add the dataframe in the question. Plus also add the code, so we could reproduce your dataframe.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I already wrote the code I have. Do you have any suggestion on how should I add the dataframe? I can't find a way to upload it. I added a new image so, you can understand better the initial dataframe

Comment: @BernardoFalcao; read this; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BernardoFalcao, you might accept and upvote when the answer fits. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Bernardo Falcao, thank you for accepting. An upvote would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
def create_cols(df,num_dates):
    for col in list(df)[1:]:
        df['{}%'.format(col)] = - ((df['{}'.format(col)].shift(num_dates) - df['{}'.format(col)]) / df['{}'.format(col)].shift(num_dates)).shift(- num_dates)
    return df

create_cols(prices,251)
```

you only would have to format the columns to percentages.